# How do you select "array"-type columns via the DBLINK function?

Tags: postgresql, dblink

Using PostgreSQL, I can easily do a select statement to return a column that is an array of the datatype `point`. i.e. `colA` is the datatype `point[]`

```
select colA from tbl
```

Returns a column that contains an array of points:

```
+-----------------------------+
|            colA             |
+-----------------------------+
| (180.0,90.0),(-180.0,-90.0) |
| (64.0,38.0),(-26.0,-40.0)   |
| etc                         |
+-----------------------------+
```

I'm certain the column is of type `point[]`, because `select colA[0]` returns as expected.

I'm trying to do this query from another server using `DBLINK()`. This is the query:

```
select
colA
from dblink(
  'my_conn',
  'select
   colA
   from public.tbl'
) as s (
  colA point[]
)
```

This query fails with this error message:

> SQL Error [22P02]: ERROR: malformed array literal: "(180,90),(-180,-90)"
>     Detail: Array value must start with "{" or dimension information.

I tested that I am able to select the datatype `point` using `DBLINK`. I.e. this query succeeds:

```
select
colA
from dblink(
  'my_conn',
  'select
   colA[0]
   from public.tbl'
) as s (
  colA point
)
```

So, my question is **How do you select an array via the DBLINK function?**.

Comment: The table you pasted looks like the output from `psql`.  But, that is not what the output of an array of points would look like in `psql`.   "because select colA[0] returns as expected": this doesn't communicate much, because we don't know what you expected it to return.

Comment: If you are using `psql`, then use `\d tbl` to see what the actual data type of the column is.  If the type actually is point[], then the dblink queries you give work for me as written (except that subscript 0 is generally unused, so I changed it to a 1)

Comment: The table output is from an ascii table generator that I like to use. By expected, I mean that specifying an index I got the first of the two values back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution I found was via casting:

1. Specify the column in `DBLINK` SQL as `TEXT`
2. Cast to text in the `DBLINK` SQL statement
3. Cast from `TEXT` to `POINT[]` outside of `DBLINK`

[PostgreSQL: What is the best way to cast from from text to point[]?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/243669/postgresql-what-is-the-best-way-to-cast-from-from-text-to-point)