# PostgreSQL: What is the best way to cast from from text to point[]?

Tags: postgresql, cast

I'm looking for a way to cast from a text value:

```
'(180,90),(-180,-90)'
```

into a point[] value:

`{"(180,90)","(-180,-90)"}`

What is the best way to do this?

One possibility that I can think of is to manipulate the string to be of this form:

```
'{"(180, 90)", "(-180,-90)"}'
```

Which I can then cast to `point[]` like so:

```
select '{"(180, 90)", "(-180,-90)"}'::point[];
```

Surely there's a better way? The solution I currently have is this:

```
select concat('{', replace(replace(<text>, '(', '"('), ')', ')"'), '}')::point[]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not any better than what you already got, but:

```
select string_to_array(replace('(180,90),(-180,-90)','),(',');('), ';')::point[];
```

If the separator token in the array would have been something else (say ";"), it would have been sufficient with:

```
select string_to_array('(180,90);(-180,-90)', ';')::point[];
```

EDIT:

If I get it right you have a foreign table like:

```
create table mytbl (p point[]);
insert into mytbl (p) 
values ( '{"(180, 90)", "(-180,-90)"}'::point[] );
```

which you access through a dblink. Would the following work ( I cant use DBLink at the moment )?

```
select string_to_array(array_to_string(p,';'),';') from mytbl;
```

Comment: I'm actually casting from point[] to a string. Is there a way to specify the join character? Then I could use this, which I think is cleaner. The reason I'm doing this is because I can't select an array over dblink https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/243659/how-do-you-select-array-type-columns-via-the-dblink-function. Do you know why?

Comment: array_to_string(a, ";"), I'm afraid I have no idea about the dblink

Comment: I think it should work... This does: `select string_to_array(array_to_string('{"(180, 90)", "(-180,-90)"}'::point[], ';'), ';') result`. However, trying that function in the DBLINK query results in an error: `[42883] ERROR: function array_to_string(box, unknown) does not exist`.

I don't know what this `box` is...